# Add a table to Elmah Error details View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, elmah

I've just started working with Elmah in an ASP.NET MVC project. I was wondering if there's anyway to add a new table to the Error details view like the one from server variables.
I know how to add some extra data to the log by using:

```
Exception newEx = new Exception("Preview Error\n"+ article.ExceptionString(),e);
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(newEx);
```

But i'm interested in adding a custom table with my local variables like this one.
[image]

Comment: I looked for something like that a while ago, but it seems there no such thing around. I ended up digging into Elmah source code and stored procedures. I'm interested though :)